# Compilation details and reachability algorithms

Tags: f#, graph, boolean-logic, reachability

Should I make an analysis of reachability of parts of a graph (called rule): a node can be reached if a certain boolean condition is verified. Each node knows only its predecessor, there are different types of nodes and not all nodes have at guard a condition to be verified. The rule is placed in a file.

I made ​the parsing of the rule, I have selected (through the use of discriminated union) and ordered the nodes in accordance with the flow of execution. Now, I should make a kind of static analysis to inform the user that, for specified conditions, some nodes are unreachable. There are multiple entry points to the graph, but only one exit point.

The professor told me to translate the Boolean conditions in F# and check it through compilation. But I noticed that the F# compiler does not give me a warning even though I have written the following code:

```
let tryCondition cond =
if cond then
    if not cond then "Not reachable"
    else "Reachable"
else "bye"
```

Or

```
let tryConditionTwo num =
match num with
| x as t when x > 0 -> match t with
                       | y when y < 0 -> "Not reachable"
                       | _ -> "Reachable"
| _ -> "bye"
```

Is there a better solution and not too much complex to implement in F# to solve this problem? Or is there an option in the compiler that allows me to get information about unreachable code?

This is an example of the graph that I have to check the reachability of the various branches. "IN" blocks are used to load the columns from a database, while "Select" blocks are used to select all and only the rows that meet a given condition. I should check statically that these conditions are mutually contradictory.

Answer (score 3):

There is no easy way to solve the problem. If you were able to write a static analysis tool that always worked, you would also solve the [Halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem) and that's (provably) impossible.

I don't think the F# compiler does any complex reachability analysis at the moment. If you want to implement this check just for Boolean conditions and Integers (as in your examples), then you could parse the F# expression, translate it to some logical formula and then use [SMT solver](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satisfiability_Modulo_Theories) to check whether there are any values for which the condition will hold.

- To parse the source code, you can either use the [open-source F#](http://fsharppowerpack.codeplex.com/) release, or you can use F# quotations (if you just want to run your tool on explicitly marked expressions). Using the later is easier for starting.
- For more information about SMT solvers, you can check out the [Z3 project](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/z3/) from Microsoft Research. You could also implement a simple version of such tool yourself - for just Boolean conditions (no numbers) you can take a look at [SAT solving algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I document and you'll know if it was what I needed. I added some notes and a picture that I hope will be illustrative.